# Если не выбран параметр то вывести всё

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Как вывести все записи если не выбрано количество комнат?

```
SELECT * FROM room 
WHERE  id_city='$city' AND people>='$people' AND rooms='$rooms'
```

Comment: Вам это нужно реализовать именно на стороне базы данных? Такое условие проще сделать в php-скрипте.

Comment: *если не выбрано количество комнат?* Что именно содержит `$rooms` в таком случае?

Comment: @Akina содержит null

Comment: А поточнее? `'null'`? каким получается текст запроса в переменной после подстановки этого `null`? вот таким: `.. AND rooms='null'` ?

Comment: @Akina да таким

Comment: Ну например так: `AND (rooms='$rooms' OR 'null'='$rooms')`.

Comment: @Akina подошло, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

обычная такая логика учитывается на этапе формирования самого запроса

```
if($rooms){
     $sql . " AND rooms = ?";
}
```

при этом обратите внимание, что нельзя подставлять никакой пользовательский ввод напрямую в запрос без предварительной обработки. используйте биндинг параметров.

с точки зрения самого SQL запроса можно вариировать выборку, например, так

```
AND ( 
     ($rooms = 0) 
      OR ($rooms > 0 AND rooms = $rooms)
  )
```